# Dangling pointer in case of integer pointer vs char pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, dangling-pointer

I am trying to understand how dangling pointers work in c++.

```
int* get_int_ptr()
{
    int i=10;
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &i;
    return ptr;
}

char* get_char_ptr()
{
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str,"Hello!");
    return(str); 
}

int main()
{
    cout << *get_int_ptr() << endl;
    cout << get_char_ptr() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is -

Warnings:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'char* get_char_ptr()':
prog.cpp:16:9: warning: address of local variable 'str' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
char str[10];
    ^
```

Output:

`10`

Can someone explain why is the value of `i` is printed in the `main()` function even when returned pointer points to `i` which has gone out of scope.

And why is the value of `str` not printed.

Is `int*` and `char*` are treated separately in terms of function scope.

Also, does using `smart_pointers` here will help in any form?

Comment: Um, you can't understand how dangling pointers "work", because they *don't work*! If you want to spend mental energy understanding what they do (i.e. how they fail), pease expend at least as much energy ensuring you never use them in real code!

Comment: Dereferencing a dangling pointer is [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means *anything could happen, including appearing to work*! The language makes no guarantees at all. It just happens that in the actual hardware, sometimes that piece of memory still contains the value it used to, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: "Can someone explain why is the value of i is printed in the main() function even when returned pointer points to i which has gone out of scope." because undefined behavior says _anything_ could happen.

Comment: Basically your question is akin to "I do not have a driver's license, so why am I able to get into a car and drive it?", or "I am driving a car without a license.  Why hasn't any policeman stopped me?".  Maybe a policeman will stop you later, maybe you will never be stopped by a policeman, etc.  It is basically "undefined" what will or won't happen to you.  Same thing if you do something illegal / dumb in C++.  You cannot guarantee what will or won't happen due to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, returning a pointer to a local variable is not guaranteed to work. So neither your `get_int_ptr` nor your `get_char_ptr` function can be expected to work.

(Foreshadowing the answer: "not guaranteed to work" is not quite the same as "guaranteed not to work".)

You experimented with your `get_int_ptr` function.  To your surprise, the calling program "correctly" printed 10.

Here's an analogy.  What you've done is just like this little story:

> I was working on my car.  I removed the front wheel to repair the brakes.  When I put the front wheel back on, I forgot to install the lug nuts, so the wheel wasn't really attached.  Then I drove to the store to buy some milk.  But the wheel did not fall off.  Why not?

And the answer is, you were very, very lucky.

Then you experimented with your `get_char_ptr` function.  And it failed.  This wouldn't be surprising, unless you imagined that the success of the `get_int_ptr` experiment somehow proved that dangling pointers are okay to use after all.  Continuing the analogy:

> The next day, with the lug nuts still missing, I drove cross-country to visit my aging grandmother.  Halfway there, while traveling at 60 mph on the highway, the front wheel suddenly flew off, and I crashed into the ditch, demolishing my car.  Why did this happen?

Needless to say, it happened because the lug nuts were missing!  There was nothing holding the front wheel on, and your apparent "success" the previous day, driving to the store in that broken condition, proved nothing.

I agree it's intriguing that one of your functions "worked" and the other one didn't.  But it was basically random happenstance.  No, there's no difference between `int*` and `char*` pointers in this regard: they're both about equally likely not to work if dangling.

Sometimes it's possible to explain why random happenstance happens the way it does.  Here, though, I can't.  I've tried your program under my compiler, and I'm seeing exactly the same result.  `get_int_ptr`'s local variable `i` tends to survive, but `get_char_ptr`'s local array `str` tends to get cleared out.  I would expect that bits of `str` might survive, but evidently not.  But, again, it doesn't really matter that we can't explain the behavior, because it's *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

It is accidental that something is printed.

Both pointers point to the local variable which stops to exist when function returns.

This the classical example of the Undefined Behavior.

Anything can happen - program may order you a pizza, explode or print something - sometimes even the correct value.